# PHP Array with Json issue

Tags: php, json

I want to achieve this using my php script:

```
{  
    "aaData":[  
        [  
            "100",
            "189",
            "2"
        ],
        [  
            "100",
            "189",
            "1"
        ],
        [  
            "100",
            "188",
            "4"
        ],
        [  
            "100",
            "188",
            "3"
        ],
        [  
            "100",
            "188",
            "2"
        ]
    ]
}
```

I am fetching data from database, and i want to put results to above format. Query looks like this:

```
SELECT user_id, module_id, action_id FROM test;
```

Please help me to put results of these 3 columns on format which i mentioned above.

Regards

Comment: Have you tried json_encode() ?

Comment: fetch loop push inside array encode

Comment: Idea is that i need to push them dynamically. So based on columns defined for select (here are 3 but they could be 5, 10 ...) i need to push them on that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PDO, you can do:

```
$result = $conn->execute("SELECT `user_id`, `module_id`, `action_id` FROM `test`");
$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
echo json_encode(array('aaData' => $rows));
```

`fetchAll` returns a 2-dimensional array of the results of the query. The `PDO::FETCH_NUM` mode makes the rows of these results be numerically-indexed arrays. Then we put this into the `aaData` element of another array, and convert it to JSON.

Comment: Thanks i am not using PDO :(

Comment: The general idea is the same no matter what interface you use. Put the results into an array, then convert the array to JSON.

Comment: `mysqli` has a `fetch_all` method, too.

Comment: If you're using the obsolete `mysql` interface, you'll have to write a loop that calls `mysql_fetch_row` to get each row, and push them onto the `$rows` array.

Comment: @nlee: You have to use either `PDO` or `mysqli_`. if you're using `mysql_` you MUST STOP RIGHT NOW because it's deprecated.